# How to return records from a subquery where the row count of the subquery is equal to X?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table named Groups structured like so...

```
+--------------+
| Id   GroupId |
+--------------+
| 1    3       |
| 2    3       |
| 3    2       |
| 1    2       |
| 2    2       |
| 3    2       |
+--------------+
```

I want to return the GroupId where Id = 1 and the other Id = 2, so the result should be 3. Here's what I've tried so far...

```
SELECT GroupId FROM Groups G1
WHERE G1.Id = 1 and exists ( select 1
FROM Groups G2
WHERE G2.Id = 2
and G1.GroupId = G2.GroupId)
```

This works fine until a group is added where both Ids exist in (group 2). Then, this fails as the subquery returned more than 1 value.

I've thought about using HAVING COUNT(*) == 2 to try and get the subquery to return the group with only 2 row counts but I'm not sure how to do that, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group by` and `having`:

```
select groupid
from groups
where id in (1, 2)
group by groupid
having count(*) = 2;
```

This assumes that the rows are unique.  If you can have duplicates, use `count(distinct id) = 2`.

If you want 1 & 2 and *no other* ids, the logic is slightly more complicated:

```
select groupid
from groups
group by groupid
having sum(case when id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when id = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       count(*) = 2;
```